# json Serialization in asp

Tags: json, asp-classic

I have currently a dataset in asp which contains my members details.

I am trying to serlize it so that it is similar to json_encode() in php which produces

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Eric","name":"Eric","2":"1","sex":"1","3":"1992","birthyear":"1992"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Tom","name":"Tom","2":"1","sex":"1","3":"1992","birthyear":"1992"}]
```

Any help here?

Comment: You mention dataset. Are you using ASP.NET which can use the DataSet class, or are you using Classic ASP? Dataset is a generic term but it would be useful to clarify this point. Posting an example of your dataset code will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**json.org**](http://json.org/) website links to two libraries, for ASP :

- [JSON for ASP.](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/)
- [JSON ASP utility class.](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without external libraries? The environment being deployed to is Super restrictive of outside .dll's. (Personally I just use Newtonsoft)