# Show the gps data on google map using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am trying to develop a gps tracker using `MVC.net` so i have a function that reload my map and point as you can see here :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map; var infowindow;
    function InitializeMap() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.7015691, 51.3821045);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }


    function markicons() {

        InitializeMap();

        var ltlng = [];
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.790991, 51.417746));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.793386, 51.404578));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.792612, 51.399404));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.787515, 51.391928));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.771040, 51.387628));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.756908, 51.387241));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.725584, 51.381827));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.710518, 51.377572));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.706555, 51.377470));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.705059, 51.377595));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.700149, 51.378081));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.698232, 51.378313));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.697542, 51.378372));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.687726, 51.379677));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.680949, 51.379919));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.676178, 51.380610));
        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.668223, 51.381307));

        map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: ltlng[i]
            });

            (function (i, marker) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }

                    infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            })(i, marker);

        }

    }

    window.onload = markicons;

</script>
```

I have a div tag to bind the function to it ,

```
 <div class="box">
        <div id="map"style="width: 100%; height: 400px">

        </div>
```

But as you can see i put my points statically ,i need my page gets the data using ajax without refreshing the page .

Here is my database structure :

[image]

as you can see the data should be fetched from the database

```
 ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.790991, 51.417746));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.793386, 51.404578));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.792612, 51.399404));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.787515, 51.391928));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.771040, 51.387628));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.756908, 51.387241));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.725584, 51.381827));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.710518, 51.377572));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.706555, 51.377470));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.705059, 51.377595));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.700149, 51.378081));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.698232, 51.378313));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.697542, 51.378372));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.687726, 51.379677));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.680949, 51.379919));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.676178, 51.380610));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(35.668223, 51.381307));
```

I create an api to get the data from database ,but i don't know how can i insert these data to google map .

```
public class locationController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/location
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
           avldb db=new avldb();
            return db.locations.tolist():
        }
}
```

Comment: An Ajax request to a php file, is that good for you?  Can you manage the database part?

Comment: @to an aspx file not php .

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to move the map around and pull down and load more markers as the user moves the map? If so, a simple ajax request, remove all markers that are not within bounds, add new markers, will do the trick.

Comment: @pookie in fact i install a gps on bus and i want track it from google map

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend that you clear all markers and update once every 10 seconds or so - I wouldn't update very frequently  (like every 1ms, for example). Just clear the markers from the map, get your location and if you want surrounding markers, just get all markers within x distance

Answer (score -1):

I don't know asp, I can't help you there.

But here is a partial answer that you can test

With ASP and you database, you should generate this string (it can be on 1 line, javascript doesn't care).

In order to test this (and yes, it works), I put it in "data.txt"

```
[
  {"tlng": [35.790991, 51.417746], "name": "Point 0"},
  {"tlng": [35.793386, 51.404578], "name": "Point 1"},
  {"tlng": [35.792612, 51.399404], "name": "Point 2"},
  {"tlng": [35.787515, 51.391928], "name": "Point 3"},
  {"tlng": [35.771040, 51.387628], "name": "Point 4"},
  {"tlng": [35.756908, 51.387241], "name": "Point 5"},
  {"tlng": [35.725584, 51.381827], "name": "Point 6"},
  {"tlng": [35.710518, 51.377572], "name": "Point 7"},
  {"tlng": [35.706555, 51.377470], "name": "Point 8"},
  {"tlng": [35.705059, 51.377595], "name": "Point 9"},
  {"tlng": [35.700149, 51.378081], "name": "Point 10"},
  {"tlng": [35.698232, 51.378313], "name": "Point 11"},
  {"tlng": [35.697542, 51.378372], "name": "Point 12"},
  {"tlng": [35.687726, 51.379677], "name": "Point 13"},
  {"tlng": [35.680949, 51.379919], "name": "Point 14"},
  {"tlng": [35.676178, 51.380610], "name": "Point 15"},
  {"tlng": [35.668223, 51.381307], "name": "Point 16"}
]
```

php has a function that turns an object into this form of string, called json_encode()

Maybe this helps: [json Serialization in asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765881/json-serialization-in-asp)

then index.htm (notice, put in your own key https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR_KEY] )

```
<div id="map"></div>
<style>
#map {
  height: 90%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR_KEY]" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map; 
var infowindow;

function InitializeMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.7015691, 51.3821045);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    // now we will load the data
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.txt',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // data is now an object that javascript can read.
        // now we feed it to  markicons()
        markicons(data);
      }
    });
}
function markicons(data) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(data[0].tlng[0]), Number(data[0].tlng[1])));
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(data[i].tlng[0]), Number(data[i].tlng[1])),
            title: data[i].name
        });
        (function (i, marker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                if (!infowindow) {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                }
                infowindow.setContent("Name: " + data[i].name);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(i, marker);
    }
}

window.onload = InitializeMap;
</script>
```

I rearranged your functions a little.  The main thing is to get the data outside of the function.